# Why is my document root being shown in PATH_INFO, PATH_TRANSLATED and PHP_SELF?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a `VirtualHost` set up, which looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName ownedmedia.vzweb07.example.co.uk
       DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/owned_media_microsite/httpdocs
       ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/owned_media_microsite/logs/error_log
       CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/owned_media_microsite/logs/access_log combined
       SetEnv ENVIRONMENT 'development'
       <Directory /var/www/vhosts/owned_media_microsite/httpdocs>
               AllowOverride All
               allow from all
               Options +Indexes
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a `.htaccess` file in the DocumentRoot which looks like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I visit `http://ownedmedia.vzweb07.example.co.uk/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1` and `var_dump` the `$_SERVER` array I see the following... (I have trimmed out some non-related values).

```
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
string(46) "/var/www/vhosts/owned_media_microsite/httpdocs"
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
string(56) "/var/www/vhosts/owned_media_microsite/httpdocs/index.php"
["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
string(43) "/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1"
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
string(3) "GET"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
string(0) ""
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
string(43) "/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(10) "/index.php"
["PATH_INFO"]=>
string(52) "/httpdocs/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1"
["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
string(123) "redirect:/index.php/httpdocs/httpdocs/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
string(62) "/index.php/httpdocs/admin/modules/load/coreg_api_module/rule/1"
```

Why does `PATH_INFO` etc contain the `httpdocs` directory?

There isn't even a directory inside `httpdocs` called `httpdocs` so there's no way `PATH_TRANSLATED` can be correct.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening? This project has been set up and is working fine on other hosts, and I have other vhosts on this machine that are not encountering the same issue.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue on my Apache

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I was able to fix this by removing everything from the document root down and then re-uploading.
Perhaps it was a mis-placed htaccess file.